# How to solve this integral? With Q-function, help with derivation.

Tags: integration

I am reading a textbook about pathloss models for wireless communications, namely Wireless Communications by Andrea Goldsmith

and it has some derivation where it goes from (sect 2.10)

$$
C = \frac{2}{R^{2}}\int_{0}^{R}rQ(a+bln\frac{r}{R})dr
$$

to this

$$
C = Q(a) + exp(\frac{2-2ab}{b^{2}})Q(\frac{2-ab}{b})
$$

Stating this is the closed-form solution of the integral.

Where Q is the Q-function(closely related to the complementary error function)

$$
Q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_x^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right) \, du.
$$

I am wondering what the intermediate steps look like? Since evaluating at r = 0 seems invalid? And evaluating at r=R simply provides C = Q(a). Obviously, I am missing some basic stuff about integrals inside integrals, but I'm not sure where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$Q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_x^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right) \, du=\frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$$C=\frac 1{R^2}\int_0^R r\,\,\text{erfc}\left(\frac{a+b \log \left(\frac{r}{R}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dr$$

Let
$$r=R e^{\frac{\sqrt{2} }{b}t-\frac{a}{b}}\implies C=\frac{\sqrt{2} }{b}e^{-\frac{2 a}{b}}\int_0^1e^{\frac{2 \sqrt{2} }{b}t} \text{erfc}(t)\,dt$$

For $$I=\int e^{\frac{2 \sqrt{2} }{b}t} \text{erfc}(t)\,dt$$ one integration by parts gives
$$I=\frac{b }{2 \sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{b}t}\, \text{erfc}(t)+\frac b {\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{\frac{2 \sqrt{2} }{b}t-t^2}\,dt$$ Complete the square and face the gaussian integral. The result follows and go back to $Q(.)$.